# does $\int_{-1}^{1} x^3(x^2+1) dx = \frac{1}{2} \int_{-1}^{1} x^2(x^2+1) dx^2 = \frac{1}{2} \int_{-1}^{1} x(x+1) dx$?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I got this:

$0 = \int_{-1}^{1} x^3(x^2+1) dx = \frac{1}{2} \int_{-1}^{1} x^2(x^2+1) dx^2 = \frac{1}{2} \int_{-1}^{1} x(x+1) dx \neq 0$

I think the third equation is wrong, but what is the correct answer?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is the last "$=$" sign:
$$ \frac{1}{2} \int_{-1}^{1} x^2(x^2+1) dx^2 = \frac{1}{2} \int_{-1}^{1} x(x+1) dx \neq 0$$
In fact, we did a substitution $t=x^2$ here, explicitly.-- But there is a mistake, as the inverse function of $t=x^2$ is not a one-value function on the interval $x\in[-1,1]$.

The correct is as below:
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^1{x^2}(x^2+1)\mathrm{d}x^2=&\int_0^1{x^2}(x^2+1)\mathrm{d}x^2+\int_{-1}^0{x^2}(x^2+1)\mathrm{d}x^2
\\
(\color{green}{\text{use}\;t=x^2})=&\int_0^1{t}(t+1)\mathrm{d}t+\int_1^0{t}(t+1)\mathrm{d}t
\\
=&\int_0^1{t}(t+1)\mathrm{d}t-\int_0^1{t}(t+1)\mathrm{d}t
\\
=&0
\end{align}
$$
which avoids that
$
x=\begin{cases}
 -\sqrt{t}\,\,/; x<0\\
 \sqrt{t}\,\,/; x\ge 0\\
\end{cases}
$.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @Jingjian Lu , you are welcome.